# Updating multiple items in one go

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I need to update items in three different lists in one event receiver. Problem is, whenever I have a user do anything at all that involves two calls to `SPListItem.Update()` in a short time frame, I get the following error:

> The sandboxed code execution request was refused because the Sandboxed Code Host Service was too busy to handle the request

I have been hunting high and low for a way to solve this problem. I have seen blog posts in MSDN telling you must change some configurations - and I can attest that they work, did it in my machine. But I can't change any settings in the production environ because we're using Sharepoint Online (i.e.: no Powershell, and also they don't want us going anywhere near Central Administration).

I have also read about batch updates. However, besides the fact that we're dealing with different lists, each item has 10+ fields that may or may not have changed, and they're not the same fields for every item in a same list, so building the XML for that would be monstruous.

Help?

Comment: Can you post more code? What config did you change to get it working on your machine?